# Running Jython in Docker Ubuntu - FileUtil not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jython

I am running Jython app in local environemnt and it works fine.
Some of the first import libraries are `FileUtil` and it loads it fine.

When I move whole app to Docker (Ubuntu) and start running it there - most of libraries load fine but this particular (FileUtil) does not get load:
`ImportError: No module named FileUtil`

What should I check and how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try to confirm if this lib is in the import path first.

Comment: How to make sure where is `import path` - where to look/how to test?